# Python / SQL - Loop to fill records based on a roll back/forward of existing populated records

Tags: python, sql, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have some data in two tables, one table is a list of dates (with other fields), running from 1st Jan 2014 until yesterday. The other table contains a year's worth of numeric data (coefficients / metric data) in 2020.

A left join between the two datasets on the date table results in all the dates being brought back with only the year of data being populated for 2020, the rest null as expected.

What I want to do is to populate the history to 2014 (and future) with the data in 2020 on a -364 day mapping.

For example

```
#+----------+-----------+
#|date      |metric     |
#+----------+-----------+
#|03/02/2018|null       |
#|04/02/2018|null       |
#|05/02/2018|null       |
#|06/02/2018|null       |
#|07/02/2018|null       |
#|08/02/2018|null       |
#|09/02/2018|null       |
#|10/02/2018|null       |
#|....      |           |
#|02/02/2019|null       |
#|03/02/2019|null       |
#|04/02/2019|null       |
#|05/02/2019|null       |
#|06/02/2019|null       |
#|07/02/2019|null       |
#|08/02/2019|null       |
#|09/02/2019|null       |
#|...       |...        |
#|01/02/2020|0.071957531|
#|02/02/2020|0.086542975|
#|03/02/2020|0.023767137|
#|04/02/2020|0.109725808|
#|05/02/2020|0.005774458|
#|06/02/2020|0.056242301|
#|07/02/2020|0.086208715|
#|08/02/2020|0.010676928|
```

This is what I am trying to achieve:

```
#+----------+-----------+
#|date      |metric     |
#+----------+-----------+
#|03/02/2018|0.071957531|
#|04/02/2018|0.086542975|
#|05/02/2018|0.023767137|
#|06/02/2018|0.109725808|
#|07/02/2018|0.005774458|
#|08/02/2018|0.056242301|
#|09/02/2018|0.086208715|
#|10/02/2018|0.010676928|
#|....      |           |
#|02/02/2019|0.071957531|
#|03/02/2019|0.086542975|
#|04/02/2019|0.023767137|
#|05/02/2019|0.109725808|
#|06/02/2019|0.005774458|
#|07/02/2019|0.056242301|
#|08/02/2019|0.086208715|
#|09/02/2019|0.010676928|
#|...       |...        |
#|01/02/2020|0.071957531|
#|02/02/2020|0.086542975|
#|03/02/2020|0.023767137|
#|04/02/2020|0.109725808|
#|05/02/2020|0.005774458|
#|06/02/2020|0.056242301|
#|07/02/2020|0.086208715|
#|08/02/2020|0.010676928|
```

Worth noting I may eventually have to go back more than 2014 so any dynamism on the population would help!

I'm doing this in databricks so I can use various languages but wanted to focus on Python / Pyspark / SQL for solutions.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.
CT

Answer (score 2):

First create new columns `month` and `year`:

```
df_with_month = df.withColumn("month", f.month(f.to_timestamp("date", "dd/MM/yyyy")))
                  .withColumn("year", f.month(f.to_timestamp("date", "dd/MM/yyyy")))
```

with `import pyspark.sql.functions as f`

Create a new DataFrame with 2020's data:

```
df_2020 = df_with_month.filter(col("year") == 2020)
                       .withColumnRenamed("metric", "new_metric")
```

Join the results on the month:

```
df_with_metrics = df_with_month.join(df_2020, df_with_month.month == df_2020.month, "left")
                               .drop("metric")
                               .withColumnRenamed("new_metric", "metric")
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do a self join using the condition that the date difference is a multiple of 364 days:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df2 = df.join(
    df.toDF('date2', 'metric2'),
    F.expr("""
        datediff(to_date(date, 'dd/MM/yyyy'), to_date(date2, 'dd/MM/yyyy')) % 364 = 0
        and
        to_date(date, 'dd/MM/yyyy') <= to_date(date2, 'dd/MM/yyyy')
    """)
).select(
    'date',
    F.coalesce('metric', 'metric2').alias('metric')
).filter('metric is not null')

df2.show(999)
+----------+-----------+
|      date|     metric|
+----------+-----------+
|03/02/2018|0.071957531|
|04/02/2018|0.086542975|
|05/02/2018|0.023767137|
|06/02/2018|0.109725808|
|07/02/2018|0.005774458|
|08/02/2018|0.056242301|
|09/02/2018|0.086208715|
|10/02/2018|0.010676928|
|02/02/2019|0.071957531|
|03/02/2019|0.086542975|
|04/02/2019|0.023767137|
|05/02/2019|0.109725808|
|06/02/2019|0.005774458|
|07/02/2019|0.056242301|
|08/02/2019|0.086208715|
|09/02/2019|0.010676928|
|01/02/2020|0.071957531|
|02/02/2020|0.086542975|
|03/02/2020|0.023767137|
|04/02/2020|0.109725808|
|05/02/2020|0.005774458|
|06/02/2020|0.056242301|
|07/02/2020|0.086208715|
|08/02/2020|0.010676928|
+----------+-----------+
```

Comment: Are you sure that is 364 and not 365?

Comment: @MykolaZotko the OP said they wanted 364?

Answer (score 1):

First you can add the timestamp column:

```
df = df.select(F.to_timestamp("date", "dd/MM/yyyy").alias('ts'), '*')
```

Then you can join on equal month and day:

```
cond = [F.dayofmonth(F.col('left.ts')) == F.dayofmonth(F.col('right.ts')),
        F.month(F.col('left.ts')) == F.month(F.col('right.ts'))]

df.select('ts', 'date').alias('left').\
join(df.filter(F.year('ts')==2020).select('ts', 'metric').alias('right'), cond)\
.orderBy(F.col('left.ts')).drop('ts').show()
```

Comment: Thanks - if the data moved so we had data for 2021, where there is no leap year, how would it be possible to accommodate it?

Comment: You can use forward-fill for missing values.